# how to extract options I saved with customize and insert it inside use-package lines?

Tags: customize, use-package

Suppose I did some customization through M-x `customize-mode` or something similar

```
 '(org-agenda-custom-commands
   '(("n" "Agenda and all TODOs"
      ((agenda "" nil)
       (alltodo "" nil))
      nil)
     ("i" "Urgent things" tags "URGENT" nil)))
```

they are inserted inside `(custom-set-variables`

Can I just cut the lines and put them inside

`(use-package org` ?

Actually do I need to?
I thought it would be aethetically pleasing to see well cleaned up init.el file..

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of preference (or aesthetics) but if you are making frequent changes you'll appreciate having all the settings in one place. Using [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/README.md) can be helpful for keeping similar configs together and being explicit about how keyconfigs, hooks and dependencies (etc) are related to a package.

If you change something with the customize interface, you can just move it into your `init.el` file as needed.

With `use-package` you could try something like...

```lisp
 (use-package org
  :config (setq org-agenda-custom-commands ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought it would be aethetically pleasing to see well cleaned up init.el file

Yes, and in my case I don't use the customize UI at all, all my config is out of the `custom-set-variables` region. `custom-set-variables` only contains assignments written by the packages I use.

If your `custom-set-variables` region is still in your init file, you may want to move it to another file, copying from my config copied from Purcell's config:

```lisp
(setq custom-file (expand-file-name "custom.el" user-emacs-directory))
(unless (file-exists-p custom-file)
  (write-region "" nil custom-file))
(when (file-exists-p custom-file)
  (load custom-file))
```

One thing to note is that `custom-set-variables` can trigger the custom `set` behavior written by the package author, while `setq` cannot. Such behavior is defined in `:set` when using `defcustom` (read the doc of `defcustom` for more). use-package's `:custom`, obviously does trigger that, as its name states.